# how to include php variable in mysqli statement

Tags: php

My question is how to include $value inside a MySQL statement. For example,

```
$value="1"
$sql="insert into table (value1) value ('value_');
```

I want to add the $value after value_. Is it possible for me to do that? If possible, could you show me the way please?
Thanks a lot...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sure, you just wrap the variable name with curly braces:

```
$sql="insert into table (value1) values ('value_{$value}');
```

But on this stage of learning you should learn and get used to PDO prepared statements to avoid the risk of mysql injections.

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql="insert into table (value1) value ('value_".$value."')";
```

Comment: this is a bad question, but dont teach him SQL INJECTIONS

Comment: @Yair.R That's not a reason to downvote the answers. I've seen enough questions where people still use `mysql` and the answers there didn't get downvoted.

Comment: I didnt downvote... other  users did :)

Comment: @Yair.R Yeah I assume the ones that voted your comment up, downvoted the answers.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you don't teach me sql injections. it's fine enough for me. i was just not sure about the way of doing it. i was lazy to try the code and yet i chose to ask. i know how to do that. don't judge person by the stupidity of question. tq